mancher + singular
I have read the following sentence in the subtitles at 1:46 in https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/sendung/tagesschau_20_uhr/video-1394840.html:

Vor so mancher Tür eines Wahllokals: Gewalt gegen Oppositionswähler.

Is there any difference in meaning between this and

Vor den Türen einiger Wahllokale ...

?
Not sure about the previous example, but can I usually replace mancher + singular with manche + plural, just like "many" and "many a" in English ? Fortunately the latter is very rare in that language nowadays.

You can use the indefinite pronoun »manch« in singular and in plural:

Sing. masc.: Mancher Mann trinkt gern Wasser.
Sing. fem.: Manche Frau trinkt gern Wasser.
Sing. neut.: Manches Kind trinkt gern Wasser.
Plural: Manche Leute trinken gern Wasser.

You can combine it with an adjective, but then only the adjective gets inflected, and it gets inflected strongly, i.e. the same way as if »manch« was an indefinite article. The word »manch« stays uninflected when combined with an adjective. (But you can use »manch« also for plural, which is not possible for an indefinite article.)

Sing. masc.: Manch schlanker Mann trinkt gern Wasser.
Sing. fem.: Manch schlanke Frau trinkt gern Wasser.
Sing. neut.: Manch schlankes Kind trinkt gern Wasser.
Plural: Manch schlanke Leute trinken gern Wasser.

The correct translation of plural manch is not many but some:

manche Leute = some people
viele Leute = many people

There is no direct translation of singular manch into English. The best you can do is to use plural instead:

manches Kind = some children
manche Kinder = some children

There is no difference in meaning between »manches Kind« and »manche Kinder«.
The program DeepL also offered me this alternative translation, of which I don't know how common it is for native English speakers:

manches Kind = many a child


I think the confusion does indeed stem with equating "manch" with "many", which would of course require a plural in English: "In front of many polling station doors... ." As you mentioned, the phrase "many a" is more similar to "manch", although "many a" cannot be used with a plural: "In front of many a polling station door... ." But "many a", while certainly understandable, is rare in modern English. It's known in certain sayings, for example "There's many a slip twixt cup and lip", but it's replaced by "many" in everyday usage.

My confusion comes from using singular to represent a plural, regardless if "manch" means "many" or "some". It does not happen in my native language and it's rare in modern English.

It is "manche schlanken Leute" in contemporary German. "Manch schlanke Leute", fürwahr, da hat sich Ihro Gnaden schon einer ältern Art der Rede befleißigt.
